# Harsh zooming after large object import

Tags: 3d-view

I imported a large .obj object into blender, and it was way too big so I scaled it down, but ever since I imported the object the zooming and the pan view and rotate view are very harsh.(they zoom too much and too radically)

Answer (score 0):

edit - prefrences - navigation - auto depth

Comment: Hi. I think some explanation of *why* this is the answer would help.